# How to corrupt a file's date modified

Tags: powershell, date, file-corruption, date-modified

We have an application that works with files. The application breaks whenever it encounters a file that has no date modified / date created (the field is literally blink in explorer and via get-childitem)

How can I create such a file in our environment to try a couple of solutions locally? I have tried dumb things like

```
$Files = ls "C:\Users\Triumvirate\tmp"
ForEach ($File in $Files){
    $File.LastWriteTime = $null
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Google hasn't been very helpful either, but I would be grateful for any tips in the right direction

Comment: No file exists that has no date modified / date created.

Comment: That isn't really true, because I've seen these files on remote session with our users and then fixed the app by moving the files to another location (that our app didn't touch). Their date modified is blank.This definitely happens, for example [here](https://central.owncloud.org/t/date-modified-field-blank-cannot-sync/10927) or [here](https://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/date-modified-is-blank-in-windows-explorer-266648.html)

Comment: Your first link : *Upon closer inspection, when viewing the file properties, the "Date Modified" field for all recently sync'd files actually says "December 31, 1969"...*. The Date Modified can be rubbish, but it's there.

Comment: Damn, you are a genius

The date modified in explorer will show up empty after

    $Files = ls "C:\Users\Triumvirate\tmp"
    ForEach ($File in $Files){
     $File.LastWriteTime = Get-Date("31/12/1969")
    }

Comment: Seems that you already found that. I was able to modify date/time of a file to empty. Created a C# code and set date to `01/01/1970 00:00:00`.

Comment: The problem is that the date was actually empty not only in explorer but also when I ran ls -s from Powershell, whereas when I set date to 1970 the date is empty in explorer (which is expected,  I guess? Works on my home pc) but the date is *not* empty when I run ls -s

Comment: Where these files are created? Is it an external software? Which OS and file system is used to store these files? Not all file systems support all fields.

Comment: Sandeep, 
These files that I saw on a user's machine are pictures, so it might be some exif shenanigans? OS is windows 10, file system is ntfs. ls -s shows no date, explorer shows no date.

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently housing the files on a device which returns rubbish dates
that are not being displayed by Explorer.

If this is a cloud-storage service and dates are important, you might consider
moving to another service, if their Support cannot supply a fix.

Comment: The dates are not only not showing up in explorer but also in powershell via Get-ChildItem -recurse

Comment: The same software might be used by Microsoft in both cases.

Comment: Harrymc,
That is definitely possible however when I manually create a file with LastWriteTime = 31/12/1969 it is blank in explorer but shows up in Get-childitem correctly, meaning that it's not *exactly* the same. The case which I am investigating has an actually empty date modified, which is something I wanted to investigate and replicate to offer a proper solution, but I don't understand how to replicate this. I have a suspicion that given the fact that these files are pictures from a camera, it's possible that there's exif corruption going on that is causing it?

Comment: Windows does not understand exif. The file-system that is exposed by that device or service has garbage in parts of the entries that Windows sees on that virtual disk.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this obscure problem that you can use.

Here are the replication steps:

1. Access the folder via bash (I dualboot, so I did this on my Ubuntu installation)
2. touch -d "1/1/1500" filename.extension (Any year < 1600 will do because I believe Fat64 dates start with 1601
3. Looking at the file in powershell or explorer will give you a blank "Date modified":

[image: Powershell]
[image: Explorer]